# how to fix AttributeError: environments in odoo?

Tags: python-3.x, environment, odoo-12

I create a separate thread in which there is the odoo environment and when I receive a new message in Skype, I form a line and try to send it to the user as a message in odoo, but I get an error

```
import skpy
import logging
import threading
import odoo

DB_NAME = 'odootest'
UID = odoo.SUPERUSER_ID

_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


registry = odoo.modules.registry.Registry.new(DB_NAME)
CR = registry.cursor()
ENV = odoo.api.Environment(CR, UID, {})


class MySkype(skpy.SkypeEventLoop):

    def onEvent(self, event):
        if isinstance(event, skpy.SkypeNewMessageEvent):
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning(event)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)

            message = ('New message from user {} at {}: \'{} \''.format(event.msg.userId,
                                                                     event.msg.time.strftime('%H:%M dd. %d.%m.%Y'),
                                                                     event.msg.content))

            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning(message)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)

            partner_id = ENV['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 2)]).partner_id.id

            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning(partner_id)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)

            ENV['mail.message'].create({'message_type': 'notification',
                                             'subtype': ENV.ref('mail.mt_comment').id,
                                             'body': message,
                                             'subject': 'Message subject',
                                             'partner_ids': [(4, partner_id), ],
                                             })
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning('send')
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)


sk = MySkype('+3767', '12qW', autoAck=True)
thread = threading.Thread(target=sk.loop)
thread.start()
```

in console

```
2019-02-21 08:45:33,569 3550 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.models.models: ---------------------------------------- 
2019-02-21 08:45:33,569 3550 WARNING ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.models.models: [SkypeNewMessageEvent]
Id: 1010
Type: NewMessage
Time: 2019-02-21 08:45:33
MsgId: 1550738733239 
2019-02-21 08:45:33,569 3550 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.models.models: ---------------------------------------- 
2019-02-21 08:45:33,570 3550 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.models.models: ---------------------------------------- 
2019-02-21 08:45:33,570 3550 WARNING ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.models.models: New message from user andreykychyc at 08:45 dd. 21.02.2019: '132123 ' 
2019-02-21 08:45:33,570 3550 INFO ? odoo.addons.skype_bot.models.models: ---------------------------------------- 
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrei/.virtualenvs/odoo-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    return self.__storage__[self.__ident_func__()][name]
KeyError: <greenlet.greenlet object at 0x7f6d76aed048>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/andrei/.virtualenvs/odoo-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skpy/main.py", line 207, in loop
    self.cycle()
  File "/home/andrei/.virtualenvs/odoo-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skpy/main.py", line 196, in cycle
    self.onEvent(event)
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/adoons_my/skype_bot/models/models.py", line 35, in onEvent
    partner_id = ENV['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 2)]).partner_id.id
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 1561, in search
    res = self._search(args, offset=offset, limit=limit, order=order, count=count)
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/res_users.py", line 422, in _search
    access_rights_uid=access_rights_uid)
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4055, in _search
    self.sudo(access_rights_uid or self._uid).check_access_rights('read')
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 4714, in sudo
    return self.with_env(self.env(user=user))
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 850, in __call__
    return Environment(cr, uid, context)
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 794, in __new__
    env, envs = None, cls.envs
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/tools/func.py", line 112, in __get__
    return self.fget.__get__(None, owner)()
  File "/home/andrei/Projects/odoo/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 767, in envs
    return cls._local.environments
  File "/home/andrei/.virtualenvs/odoo-venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/werkzeug/local.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: environments
```

as you can see from the logs, the message is generated but then the code stops and an error occurs what can be the problem and how to deal with it

Answer (score 2):

need to use `with`:

```
    _logger.info('--------' * 5)
    _logger.warning(message)
    _logger.info('--------' * 5)

    with odoo.api.Environment.manage():
        try:

            partner_id = ENV['res.users'].search([('id', '=', 2)]).partner_id.id

            _logger.info('--------' * 5)
            _logger.warning(partner_id)
            _logger.info('--------' * 5)

            ENV['mail.message'].create({'message_type': 'notification',
                                             'subtype': ENV.ref('mail.mt_comment').id,
                                             'body': message,
                                             'subject': 'Message subject',
                                             'partner_ids': [(4, partner_id), ],
                                             })
        finally:
            ENV.cr.commit()

    _logger.info('--------' * 5)
    _logger.warning('send')
    _logger.info('--------' * 5)
```